# Aggregating different rows in one column SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate

Sorry, I didn't come up with a good title for the question, so feel free to change it accordingly.

I may describe my question with a minimal example in MS SQL server 2012:

```
 create table #tmp
(
  RowID varchar(10),
  SectionCode int,
  SectionName varchar(10)
)

insert into #tmp values('Record1' , 1 , 'AB');
insert into #tmp values('Record1' , 2 , 'CD');
insert into #tmp values('Record1' , 3 , 'EF');
insert into #tmp values('Record2' , 1 , 'AB');
insert into #tmp values('Record2' , 4 , 'GH');
insert into #tmp values('Record2' , 5 , 'IJ');
insert into #tmp values('Record3' , 2 , 'CD');
insert into #tmp values('Record3' , 5 , 'IJ');
```

I am trying to create a one row per record result in which every section is a column and if there is a row associated with a section, the corresponding column value is increased. This is (not) what I want (the same record data on different rows)

```
select  RowID, 
    case when SectionName = 'AB' then 1 else 0 end as [AB Section] , 
    case when SectionName = 'CD' then 1 else 0 end as [CD Section] , 
    case when SectionName = 'EF' then 1 else 0 end as [EF Section] , 
    case when SectionName = 'GH' then 1 else 0 end as [GH Section] , 
    case when SectionName = 'IJ' then 1 else 0 end as [IJ Section] 
                                from #tmp
group by RowID , SectionName
```

which gives this output:

[image: Wrong Output Result]

I need this:

[image: Correct Output]

Thanks in advance

Comment: As mentioned by @bill, value of IJ for Record2 is 1. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pivot for this as below and manipulate the values of sections however you want.

```
SELECT rowid
,CASE 
    WHEN ab IS NULL
        THEN 0
    ELSE 1
    END AS ab
,CASE 
    WHEN cd IS NULL
        THEN 0
    ELSE 1
    END AS cd
,CASE 
    WHEN ef IS NULL
        THEN 0
    ELSE 1
    END AS ef
,CASE 
    WHEN gh IS NULL
        THEN 0
    ELSE 1
    END AS gh
,CASE 
    WHEN ij IS NULL
        THEN 0
    ELSE 1
    END AS ij
FROM (
SELECT *
FROM #tmp
PIVOT(MAX(Sectioncode) FOR Sectionname IN (
            AB
            ,CD
            ,EF
            ,GH
            ,IJ
            )) pvt
) tab
```

I think the result you shown is not correct for record id 2. ij of record id 2 should be 1.

Comment: Thanks, is your solution better performance-wise? It seems more complicated to me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
select RowID, 
       sum(case when SectionName = 'AB' then 1 else 0 end) as [AB Section] , 
       sum(case when SectionName = 'CD' then 1 else 0 end) as [CD Section] , 
       sum(case when SectionName = 'EF' then 1 else 0 end) as [EF Section] , 
       sum(case when SectionName = 'GH' then 1 else 0 end) as [GH Section] ,
from #tmp
group by RowID;
```

That is, you need aggregation functions.  And the `group by` should contain the columns that you want to define each row (i.e. only the `RowId`).

Comment: "the corresponding column value is increased" hints at `sum ( .. 1  ..0)` i guess.

Comment: @Serg . . . That makes sense.  The sample data does not distinguish between the two cases.